# Preventing text from word wrapping, min-width?

Tags: html, css

I'm just getting started in web and one of my first tasks is to fix some of the cross browser UI issues.  In firefox and internet explorer, this code looks fine:

```
<div id="readTypeBtns" style="text-align: left;margin-left: -30px">
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input value="First Read" id="firstread" type="radio">First Read</label>
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input value="Second Read" id="secondread" type="radio">Second End</label>
</div>
```

When I look at this in Chrome, the text First Read and Second Read word wrap which makes the radio button and text not be on the same line.  I was wondering why this happens.  I played around a bit and I saw I could hardcode some min-width for each, but that didn't seem to be like a "best" solution for me.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: having `input` inside `label` is right.???

Comment: @DipeshParmer: I believe that works fine, although it may be a better practice to have input tags outside of the labels. There's some disagreement on which is better. The idea is to establish semantic context, although I disagree with doing so this way. Using matching id's is another way to establish semantic (and logical) context.

Comment: @DipeshParmar yes placing the input inside a label is valid HTML.

Comment: Could you create a demo (using jsfiddle.net, or something comparable)? So we could see the problem occurring? Adding a screenshot to the Question might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS [white-space](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space) property:

```
label {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you put your style details? wrapping is not automatic other than if you had some other element or style rule that forces it to wrap

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the code to this:

```
<div id="readTypeBtns" style="text-align: left;margin-left: -30px">
    <label class="radio inline" for="firstread">First Read</label>
    <input value="First Read" id="firstread" type="radio">
    <label class="radio inline" for="secondread">Second End</label>
    <input value="Second Read" id="secondread" type="radio">
</div>
```

Basically, `<label></label>` should not contain the input, but should include a `for=""` attribute that includes the `id` of the input it's a label for.